# Apache Nifi- Must declare the scalar variable @P7UpdateKey Error

Tags: apache-nifi

When I want to **update** the database with **PutDatabaseRecord** in **Apache nifi 1.16.0** I got below error:

```
Routing to failure.: Must declare the scalar variable "@P7UpdateKey".
```

But there is no problem when **insert** in the database.

I think there was such a problem when I updated to version **1.16.0**. But I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Same problem for sql server.